# SOLR ranking large search terms higher

Tags: solr, n-gram

I am probably missing something simple here. I have the following configuration under my SOLR schema:

```
                <analyzer type="index">
                        <!-- <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])" replacement=""/> -->
                        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="100" />
                </analyzer>

                <analyzer type="query">
                        <!--<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9\s])" replacement=""/> -->
                        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                </analyzer>

        </fieldType>
```

And I have the following two documents in my index:

```
{
        "app_name":"abd cad",
        "id":"app:75751146",
        "_version_":1727607795167002624}

{
        "user_name":"ab cad",
        "id":"user:75751146",
        "_version_":1727607795167002624}
```

Then I am trying to do a phrase search based on ngram fields defined above:

```
app_name_ngram:"ab c" OR user_name_ngram:"ab c"
```

The results appear like the following:

```
{
        "app_name":"abd cad",
        "id":"app:75751146",
        "_version_":1727607791167002624}

{
        "user_name":"ab cad",
        "id":"app:75751146",
        "_version_":1727607795167002624}
```

It looks like SOLR is ranking the score of app_name ngram higher than the user_name ngram, what I would ideally want is to match it against the provided phrase "ab c" (kinda like shortest match first?) so that the document containing the username "ab cad" appears first instead of "abd cad". How to achieve this in SOLR?

Comment: check by using edis max query parser and boost the field...https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html

Comment: I guess your search is not interpreted as phrase search